# Auto scrolling the scrollview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimage

i have one scrollview in my view2 ,when i open that view2 i want to scroll the scrollview contents in x axis i tried this one buts not working for me..please help

```
  self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;

CGFloat scrollHeight = 100;
[UIView animateWithDuration:10
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                 animations:^{
                     self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, scrollHeight);
                 }
                 completion:nil];
```

Comment: Are you trying to scroll to a specific position, or are you trying to animate scrolling to the specific position?

Comment: No my image view displaying images when i scroll manually,so i want an auto scroll in x direction so it automaticall shhow the images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code in your viewDidload

```
 [Scrollview setContentOffset:CGPointMake(-0.5,Scrollview.contentOffset.y)
                                animated:YES];
```

Thats it..Now at the loading time of your view controller the scrollview move to 0.5  in negative x coordinate

Answer (score 1):

When you have moidified content size of scroll view, it will get scroll..

Try this..

```
[scrollView setContentSize:modifiedSize];
```

**Note :** when width more than 320 or height more than height of the view , it'll scroll.

Comment: This will work. ` [_thumbnailList setContentSize:CGSizeMake(modified_Width, modified_height);`. You have to calculate width and height. If you want to horizontal scroll, then modify width only.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use:

```
[myScroll scrollRectToVisible: (CGRect)  animated: (BOOL)];
```

example:

```
[myScroll scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(myScroll.frame.origin.x,myScroll.frame.origin.y,500,0)  animated: NO];
```

Answer (score -2):

My solution I wrote before didn't work.

But this will:

But I did it with performSelector:withDelay instead, and use the setContentOffset with a CGPoint which worked.

You should make a method which should call itself all time, and increase the x or y contentOffset all the time.

The easiest way to do this is to make an ivar, and you update this value all the time in the method which will be called all the time.

Comment: There are, you're sending a CGFloat to a CGPoint.

Comment: i didnt get the solution yet

Comment: I edited my answer with a solution I tried myself. You can do that in 5 minutes or so.

Comment: can u give me the code?  my scrollview name is _thumbnaillistview